# Regular expression for adding <br> after every space

Tags: javascript, regex

So i have

```
let templateKeyword = <span>Medical Sales Executive</span>
```

How to add Regex so it adds 
 elements after every space

The result I want to achive is

```
let templateKeyword = <span>Medical <br>Sales <br>Executive</span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Jan It could be React JSX. Who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's make sure `templateKeyword` is a string.

```
let templateKeyword = "<span>Medical Sales Executive</span>"
```

You can simply use `string.replace()`:

```
templateKeyword = templateKeyword.replace(/\s+/g, ' <br>')
console.log(templateKeyword) // "<span>Medical <br>Sales <br>Executive</span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = "My simple text";
const newLineAfterEveryWord = text.split(/((?:\w+ ){1})/g).filter(Boolean).join("\n");
console.log(newLineAfterEveryWord)
```